# Android TTS error while synthesizing text in specific voice after latest TTS update

Tags: android, android-tts

I am using TTS to synthesize text using android TTS in particular voice. It was working fine before I updated the Text-to-speech app. I have used following code to set the voice. I have debugged this and it sets voice correctly.

```
Voice voice = null;

for (Voice tmpVoice : getInstance().mTTS.getVoices()) {
    if (tmpVoice.getName().toLowerCase().contains(languageCode.toLowerCase() + "-in")) {
        if (tmpVoice.getName().toLowerCase().contains("male")) {
            voice = tmpVoice;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (voice != null) {
    mTTS.setVoice(voice);
}
```

This is the error I am getting in logcat

```
2020-04-28 12:45:03.860 29833-30009/? E/native: vocaine.h:213 Morphing target `male_1` not found.
2020-04-28 12:45:03.860 29833-30009/? E/native: vocoding.h:309 Error: !(vocaine->SetMorphing(target.reference()))
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: vocoding.h:285 Error: !(SetMorphing(advanced.morphing(), vocaine))
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: vocoding.cc:135 Error: !(SetMorphing(utt, mcep_bandap_vocaine_.get()))
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: lstm_synthesizer_stream_base.cc:127 Error: !(algo_.RunOneFrame(utterance, frame.vocoder_param(), frame_index_, GetParent(frame), sample))
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: lstm_synthesizer_stream_base.cc:167 Error: !(SynthesizeWaveform(*output_, frame, &sample))
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: vocoding_stream.cc:163 Error: !(FillBuffer(&finished))
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: vocoding_stream.cc:221 Failed trying to do buffered synthesis.
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: utterance_streaming_stream.cc:155 Error: output == nullptr
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: sync_pipeline_runner.cc:71 Pipeline stream controller_events failed: UNKNOWN: output == nullptr [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='SpeechErrorSpace::SpeechError(-79201)']
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/native: tts_controller.cc:361 Read operation failed!
2020-04-28 12:45:03.861 29833-30009/? E/TTS.EventProcessor: readBuffered returned null, failing synthesis
2020-04-28 12:45:03.868 29833-30009/? E/TTS.LocalSynthesizer: synthesizeWithoutLoadingVoice() failed
2020-04-28 12:45:03.868 29833-30009/? E/TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis failure with error status code: -3
```